# Oracle give more priority to like %term than %term%

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which goes something like this

```
select city_desc from mst_city where upper(city_desc) like upper('%branch%')
```

It populates both the result `those which start with branch` and `those which contains branch`. In a random order.

I want to order it such that the result first shows all the search results of `those which start with branch` and then all of `those which contains branch`.

How can i do that. I know i might have to use `Order By` Clause. But i am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a sort order with a condition on 'BRANCH%':

```
select city_desc from mst_city where upper(city_desc) like '%BRANCH%'
order by case when upper(city_desc) like 'BRANCH%' then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 6):

Try below solution:

```
WITH mst_city AS
  (SELECT 'branch test' AS city_desc FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'test branch test' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'a branch' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'branch' FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'something different' FROM dual)
SELECT
    city_desc
  FROM (
    SELECT
        city_desc,
        CASE
          WHEN UPPER(city_desc) LIKE 'BRANCH%' THEN 1
          ELSE 2
        END AS match_order
      FROM mst_city
    WHERE
      UPPER(city_desc) LIKE '%BRANCH%'
    )  
ORDER BY match_order;
```

Comment: No need to use a derived table, but yes, this is how it could be done.